# GraphQL Variable - Error Unknown argument

Tags: api, graphql

I am trying to use GraphQL Variables for the below StarWars GraphQL API and getting error message. Could someone help me with the proper use of variable on **title** in postman -

```
POST - https://swapi-graphql.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/index
```

**GraphQL Body:**

```
query Query ($title: String!) {
  allFilms {
    films (where: {title: {_eq: $title}}){
      title 
      director
      releaseDate
      speciesConnection {
        species {
          name
          classification
          homeworld {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
"message": "Unknown argument \"where\" on field \"films\" of type \"FilmsConnection\".",
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are mixing vanilla GraphQL syntax with Hasura syntax (just a guess). If you check the provided schema of the URL you are trying to query it does not list `where` as an argument:

https://studio.apollographql.com/public/star-wars-swapi/variant/current/schema/reference

It only has `after`, `before`, `last` and `first`

Here is one query that works (without any arguments):

```
query Query {
  allFilms  {
    films {
      id
      title 
      director
      releaseDate
      speciesConnection {
        species {
          name
          classification
          homeworld {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```